# switch in switch, does the outer case break if inner case break

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, break

In languages that have `switch`, usually a `break;` statement is needed. What if a `switch` within a `switch` statement? Is it necessary to put a `break;` statement in the outer `switch` when the inner `switch` has a `break;`? e.g.:

```
// outer switch
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        // inner switch
        switch (b) { // this inner switch breaks either way.
            case (2):
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break; // is this outer break still necessary?
    default:
        break;
}
```

I hope someone can help me to understand the logic more deeply and accurately.

Comment: A `break` always relates to the closes surrounding `switch` or loop. So if you have a loop inside a case, and a `break` inside that loop, then you break the loop and not the switch. Same with `switch` inside `switch`, an inner `break` only breaks the inner `switch`.

Comment: So yes, you need one.

Comment: "does the outter case break if inner case break": NO! :-)

Comment: My question back : Why would you even want to write something like this? Code like that is pretty hard to read, split it into smaller functions (call switch(b) in a seperate function) and the logic become a lot easier to read/maintain. (reduce cyclomatic complexity)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Indeed, the loop and switch example is right to the heart. Thanks!

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer It is not a particular programme that I am writing. I asked this because I have this assumption in mind and I don't know the answer. I think it is dangerous for some one to write something that he don't understand. I totally agree with you, readability is very important.

Comment: Oh nice, so it was a toy example to help you understand.nsorybi missed that. And yes it is good to understand things you are working with. Happy coding!

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer It's more like that example gave me a hit on the head (a ```break```) while I was forcing my head through the weird ```loop``` that I created for myself.

Comment: Don't worry we've all been there (and debuggers are a real help then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `break` statements are useful. This gives the language greater flexibility, and it keeps the language itself simpler to work with.

You seem to be thinking of a simple situation, where the nested `switch` is choosing which one thing to do. This is often a good design. However, what if more needs to be done? There might be more work to do after breaking out of the inner switch.

```
// outer switch
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        // inner switch
        switch (b) {
            case 2:
                std::cout << "The b value is acceptable.\n";
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "The inner default.\n";
                break;
        }
        std::cout << "The first case has finished.\n";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

If the inner `break` jumped out of the outer `switch` in this example, you would never see the output `The first case has finished.` Limiting the impact of a `break` allows for more complex code flow. (Not that complex code is desirable, but it's nice to have options.)

On top of that, if your code is not kept simple, it could quickly become difficult to deduce what the impact of a `break` statement is. You mentioned `switch` statements, but `break` statements also affect loops. If a `switch` is inside a loop, should a `break` in the `switch` also break out of the loop? What if the loop was itself inside a `switch` (that is, if you nest the statements `switch` - `while` - `switch`)? What would you expect a `break` in the inner `switch` to do? Exiting everything is unlikely to be desired. Besides, there is already a language feature that allows breaking out of multiple nesting levels (known as `return`).

There is a design principle that says to keep it simple. If your code is simple, you won't have these monster situations to worry about. At the same time, the principle also applies to language design. If the syntax rules for the language are kept simple (a `break` statement consistently breaks out of a single statement), then life is easier for the people using the language.

Comment: Your answer gave me more confusion, in a good way, please don't get me wrong. It opens up my way of thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> // is this outter break still neccessary?

Yes.

Alternatively you could show the nested `switch` inside a function and `return` instead of `break`. Likely far more readable.